# Could Buzz Lightyear's crew ever have returned to the world before their accident?

Tags: time-travel, space-exploration, space-colonization, pixar, lightyear

In Lightyear, Buzz's primary motivation is to help the crew of the Turnip return to their lives before the crash. However, it's unclear if the crew ever could have gone back to "life as normal". If they were in stasis on the exploration ship on a presumably extended voyage, hadn't they already sacrificed their lives from before? Especially if the Turnip was moving at fast enough speeds to be affected by time dilation itself?